# Auth0 authentication with Angular6

Tags: authentication, angular6, auth0, keycloak, vert.x

I have an Angular frontend and a restful Vertx backend and I am trying to let only authenticated users send requests to the backend.

For this I followed the [example by Paul Bakker](http://paulbakker.io/java/jwt-keycloak-angular2/)

Unfortunately he relies on the angular2-jwt library, which seems to be not compatible with Angular6...

How can I reqrite the following code to work in Angular6:

```js
...
import { provideAuth } from 'angular2-jwt';
...

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...,
    provideAuth({
      globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}],
      noJwtError: true,
      tokenGetter: () => {
        return window['_keycloak'].token;
      }
    })],
  ...
})
...
```

I tried to use the @auth0/angular-jwt library. But that doesnt seem to work, as I get 401s from my backend server...

```js
...
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
...

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: () => {
          return window['_keycloak'].token;
        },
        whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:8080', 'localhost:8085']
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
   ...
  ],
  ...
})
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Question has become irrelevant. The code actually works just fine the way I posted it.
My problem was in the backend. The backend didnt properly parse and validate the JWT, which resulted in the 401 error...